# Vim syntax match only word

Tags: vim, syntax

I am trying to figure out a way to highlight certain typedefs that I use commonly. For example:

```
syn match U64 "u64"
hi def link U64 Type
```

This works in that "u64" is in fact marked as a type. The issue is that if I were to make a variable "u64 u64copy" (Just an example, don't get hung up on whether or not something would actually have that name) "u64" in "u64copy" is still highlighted. I have thought about regions, but I don't know what region I would set, as this could be an issue anywhere in code.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add word boundaries to the regex:

```
syn match U64 "\<u64\>"
```

The tokens `\<` and `\>` match the zero length sequence at the start and the end of a word, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default C syntax script (for example) in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim`, you'll notice that there's a special `:syntax keyword` command.

```
syn keyword cType       int long short char void
```

`:syntax match` takes a regular expression; it's too powerful (and unnecessary) for your use case. I'd recommend to also stick to the naming convention and prepend the filetype (e.g. `c`) to your syntax group name:

```
syn keyword cU64 u64
hi def link cU64 Type
```

Or, just add to the built-in syntax group:

```
syn keyword cType u64
```